# Error: (sudo: unable to change to root gid: Operation not permitted)

Tags: mount, virtualbox, sudo, administrator

I have installed Oracle VirtualBox on my Windows 10 machine. As a guest OS I installed Ubuntu 16.04.04.

When I open the terminal on Ubuntu and run a command like:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get the following errors:

```
sudo: unable to change to root gid: Operation not permitted
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Actually I can't execute any sudo command. Any one knows how to diagnose/solve the problem?

I should metion that I am logged in using the guest account. So when I enter `groups` I get

```
guest-rqj3wa
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal behavior of guest account. it's not permitted for guest account to run commands like `su` or `sudo` because of security concerns. Otherwise anyone could sit behind your desk and do whatever he wanted to your system like installing/removing anything.

And remember that when you are logged in as a normal user, to run `sudo` you have to be a member of "sudo" group.